# Power BI is not getting included in Stream Analytics template json

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, powerbi, azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics

Have created a Stream Analytics project in visual studio, with input as event hub and output as Power BI. On building the project, the resulting template json does not include the power bi output details.

Below is the details of output.json. I see power bi properties mentioned against **PowellBIProperties**. Is this right ? This file gets generated based on values entered through UI interface in Visual studio.

```
{
  "EventHubProperties": null,
  "BlobStorageProperties": null,
  "SQLDatabaseProperties": null,
  "TableStorageProperties": null,
  "ServiceBusQueueProperties": null,
  "ServiceBusTopicProperties": null,
  "DocumentDbProperties": null,
  "PowellBIProperties": {
    "RefreshToken": "XXX",
    "TokenUserPrincipalName": "XXX",
    "TokenUserDisplayName": "XXX",
    "Dataset": "XXX",
    "Table": "XXX",
    "GroupId": "XXX",
    "GroupName": "XXX"
  },
  "AzureDataLakeStoreProperties": null,
  "AzureFunctionProperties": null,
  "DataSourceCredentialDomain": null,
  "Name": "pbiOutput",
  "DataSourceType": "Power BI",
  "Serialization": null,
  "ScriptType": "Output"
}
```

The resulting template.json has output as:

```
"outputs": [
      {
        "name": "bcbpBIOutput",
        "properties": {}
      }
    ],
```

Have tried changing the **PowellBIProperties** to **PowerBIProperties**. Still the same template gets generated.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, the ARM template for Stream Analytics does not support PowerBI or Azure Data Lake outputs. At least, that's the errors I got when creating and trying to deploy a Stream Analytics project from Visual Studio last month.